# Why can't I place a bounty on a question?

Tags: support, bounty

Why can't I place a bounty on [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/85050/5275)? Is there a rule stating that a question cannot have a negative vote count to place a bounty on it?

Answer (score 3):

The *question* is eligible, but *you* are not (currently).  There is a [maximum of three active bounties per user](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties).  After you award one of your [other bounties](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/5275/danf?tab=bounties&sort=active), you'll be able to post one on this question.

Comment: Ah! I forgot that I had posted others, the other day. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @DanF one of yours ends tomorrow (and of course you can award it early if you like), so you won't have to wait long.